# Для чего используется php-dom?

Tags: php, linux, centos, установка

Появилась необходимость установить пакет php-dom.

> Конфигурация:
>
> - WEB-Сервер: Apache
> - ОС: CentOS 7.x
> - Виртуальная машина: BitrixVM
> - Версия PHP: 7.1.23

---

Пробовал установить следующей командой:

```
yum install php-dom
```

После установки перезагрузил httpd:

```
service httpd restart
```

Для проверки установился ли пакет пробовал смотреть вывод:

```
phpinfo()
```

Выводил список установленных пакетов:

```
yum list installed
```

php-dom там нет. За то есть пакеты php-xml и libxslt. 
Не знаю почему, но в разных местах пишут разные команды установки разных пакетов

---

### Вопрос

Для чего он используется?

Как его установить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP DOM Устанавливается по умолчанию. Служит для работы с xml и html. Представляет xml/html документ в виде дерева. 
Если по каким-то причинам небыл установлен по умолчанию - установите пакет

```
yum install php71w-xml
```

и перезапустите апач

Comment: Как проверить результат установки? После выполнения команды выдает следующее: `No package php71w-xml available.`

Comment: Я вижу вы дополнили вопрос. Он у Вас стоит. 
php-xml это он.

Comment: Хорошо, почему в вашем варианте `php71w-xml`?

Comment: Так называется этот пакет для CentOS